# How to properly format Http multipart/form-data request to upload file to the server

Tags: ruby, http, file-upload, tcp, http-headers

I have a simple node js server/app that receive files. I have tried uploading jpeg files with CURL and works perfectly.I have tried with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) also works fine.But when i try to upload jpeg with simple ruby script through Tcp socket it doesn't work.The request is received by the server but with no file object.In Node js server route i am debugging the request like so `console.log(request.body);` and this returns `undefined`. With Curl and postman i get a proper request object(file).This seems like my http request in the ruby script is not formatted properly, Can anybody point out what am i doing wrong here?Thank you in advance.Here is my ruby script.

```
require 'socket'   

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8080

client = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

client.write("POST /api/binary HTTP/1.1\r\n")
client.write("Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n")
client.write ("Accept: */* \r\n")
client.write ("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x\r\n")
client.write ("\r\n")
client.write("AaB03x"+ "\n" + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='datafile'; filename='cam.jpg' \n Content-Type: image/jpeg \r\n")

data = File.open("./dom.jpg", "rb") {|io| io.read}
client.write (data)
client.write("boundary=AaB03x\r\n")
client.write ("\r\n") 
client.close
```

**Generated code snipet from postman**

```
POST /api/binary HTTP/1.1
Host: myapp.herokuapp.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c15a79a2-3a4b-0555-a876-9032afeab5de
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename=""
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Comment: Your ruby code connects to localhost, but generated HTTP request seems not to match it.

Comment: The postman is connect to my deployed app(remote server).I sent a file with CURL to my localhost though and it works fine. The only issue is when i use the script i created whether i send to localhost or remote server i get `undefined` request object.

Answer (score 0):

I was not passing `Content-Length: length` Final version that works is this one.

```
require 'socket'   

host = "myapp.herokuapp.com"
port = 80

client = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

client.write("POST /api/binary HTTP/1.1\r\n")
client.write("Host: #{host}\r\n")
client.write ("Accept: */*\r\n")
client.write ("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x\r\n")

body = "--AaB03x\r\n"
body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='datafile'; filename='cam.jpg'\r\n"

body << "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
body << "\r\n"
data = File.open("./pic.jpg", "rb") {|io| io.read}

body << data
body << "\r\n"

body << "--AaB03x--\r\n"

client.print "Content-Length: #{body.bytesize}\r\n"

client.print "\r\n"

client.print body

client.close
```